# How to use inline image src with data coming from database in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting products data from the database as an array of objects each object contains a single product data for example:

```
{
    "productId": "ASPS",
    "productName": "adidas superstar",
    "productPrice": 450,
    "productImage": "ASPS",
    "productImage1": "ASPS-1",
    "productImage2": "ASPS-2",
    "productImage3": "ASPS-3",
    "productImage4": "ASPS-4"
 }
```

now I'm using array mapping to display each object as a product card in the products listing component like this:

```
// importing react
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// importing axios
import Axios from 'axios';

// importing components
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';

export default function Products() {
    const [productsList, setproductsList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/getproducts').then((response) => {
            setproductsList(response.data)
        });
    }, [])

    return (
        <section>
            <div className="productsListingContainer">
                <div className="productsListing">
                    {productsList.map((value) => {
                        // rendering product cards
                        return (
                            <ProductCard key={value.productId} dataFromParent={value} />
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

the ProductCard component is a class based component and I'm using "this.props" to get all the data from parent -> "ProductListing component", now when I try to display product image I use this:

```
<img src={require(`./../../assets/products/${this.props.dataFromParent.productImage}.png`)} alt='Product' />
```

but nothing appears, so how can I fix this?

Comment: why did you use `require` in source?

Comment: could you try 

```<img src=`./../../assets/products/${this.props.dataFromParent.productImage}.png` alt='Product' />
```

Comment: I did some research and I found out the I should use require in the image src if I'm using a template literals

Comment: this <img src=`./../../assets/products/${this.props.dataFromParent.productImage}.png` alt='Product' /> that you recomended gives me error "'{' expected."

Comment: I didn't remove the `}` mistakenly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `.default` to the src.
something like this:

```
<img src={require(`./../../assets/products/${this.props.dataFromParent.productImage}.png`).default} alt='Product' />
```